# logarithmic color scale in google.visualization.Calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

[Google's calendars](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar) look good when the numbers used are of similar value (e.g.: 350, 300, 250, 353) - but unfortunately not so well if the variance is a bit higher (e.g.: 0, 52000, 604, 1350).

Is there a way to change the scale function of the colors (for example a logarithmic scale)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the color scale to be logarithmic. Instead I would try to scale the data.

Using 
`google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date', 'Sales', {type:'string', role:'tooltip', p:{'html':true}}],
  [new Date(2015,0,1), Math.log(100),generateTooltip("1 January 2015 - 100")]
]`.

This'll result in using the log value to the color scale, but showing the tooltip you generate with your `generateTooltip` function.

In this case mine looks like:

```
function generateTooltip(inputString){
   return '<div style="padding:8px; font-size:13pt;">' + inputString + '</div>'   
}
```

[Tooltips documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content).
[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/kvme2f7j/2/).

Comment: Thanks! The only missing part is that the legend (showing the min and max) is now also logarithmic.

Comment: This problem is also in your fiddle. (if you look at the right top of your calendar, you can see that the values are also logarithmic)